# sql trigger is not working help me out

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter $$
drop TRIGGER if EXISTS upflttyprateTrig
create TRIGGER upflttyprateTrig

AFTER UPDATE ON flttyprate
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO `histflttyprate` (
               `flttyprate_Id`, 
               `flttyprate_Flttyp_Id_Fk`, 
               `flttyprate_Date_Eff`, 
               `flttyprate_Date_Ineff`, 
               `flttyprate_IFR`, 
               `flttyprate_Single`, 
               `flttyprate_Multi`, 
               `flttyprate_Rate_Per_Hr`, 
               `flttyprate_Night_Surchage`, 
               `flttyprate_Status`, 
               `flttyprate_Token`) 
VALUES (        
                NEW.flttyprate_Id,
                NEW.flttyprate_Flttyp_Id_Fk, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Date_Eff, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Date_Ineff, 
                NEW.flttyprate_IFR, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Single, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Multi, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Rate_Per_Hr, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Night_Surchage, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Status, 
                NEW.flttyprate_Token);

END$$
```

is not working why what is actual syntax mysqlversion 5.0

Comment: "is not working" is a very poor problem description. Please state clearly what errors its giving you, what output you are getting, and what you expected it should return.

Comment: What is the actual MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

The 'IF EXISTS' clause is not supported in DROP TRIGGER statement.
And add a delimiter after 'DROP TRIGGER...' statement.

---

**EDIT**
Read the information about trigger's existance from `information_schema`.`triggers` table; then drop trigger. Do it in the application or write a stored procedure.

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE drop_trigger()
BEGIN
  SET @exist = NULL;

  SELECT 1
  INTO
    @exist
  FROM
    information_schema.triggers
  WHERE
    trigger_schema = 'test'
    AND trigger_name = 'trigger1';

  IF @exist IS NOT NULL THEN
    DROP TRIGGER test.trigger1;
  END IF;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i want proper drop  trigger syntax fot it

Comment: I have checked. IF EXISTS is supported, but in MySQL - 5.0.32 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html

Comment: can you give me query of stored procedure to drop the trigger